# Once I activate admin, Django under mod_wsgi can't find other URLs

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to do the Django tutorial. Part 1 went OK (i.stack.imgur.com/US5GN.jpg)

However, once I activate the admin site the root I get (i.stack.imgur.com/EXfE4.jpg). **Edit** (as S.O. doesn't yet allow me to post images; thanks, cberner):

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:        http://dj1.net/
Using the URLconf defined in dj1_net.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

`dj1.net` is my test domain (editing `/etc/hosts`), and while `dj1.net/admin/` now works as expected, I don't know why `dj1.net/` throws this error once I uncomment (as instructed) the line

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

under `mysite/urls.py` (in my case `dj1_net/urls.py`). It seems to me everything should work as before *unless* the GET request is against `/admin/`.

My stack: a Debian 6.0 VPS with Apache and mod_wsgi. **I want to avoid Django's built-in server**: if I can't deploy it for real, I'd rather know earlier rather than later. In fact, for easy PHP support I'm very interested in an Apache-based solution.

For further reference, here is my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/dj1.net`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dj1.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dj1_net
    Alias /static/ /var/www/dj1_net/static/
    Alias /media/ /var/www/dj1_net/media/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/dj1_net/django.wsgi
    WSGIProcessGroup dj1_net
    WSGIDaemonProcess dj1_net processes=2 threads=16 maximum-requests=1000 display-name=apache-dj1_net-wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally, here is `/var/www/dj1_net/django.wsgi`:

```
import sys
import os
import os.path
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'dj1_net.settings'
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
application = WSGIHandler()
```

Just to be upfront, I know close to nil about Apache server configuration *and* WSGI. I do, however, want to make this set-up work before embarking in Django. I followed a mix of [the official instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) and [this post](http://mindref.blogspot.com.es/2011/08/debian-django-apache-modwsgi.html), since I frankly couldn't make get Django to work applying either instructions verbatim. I'm afraid the bottom of the problem must lie there...

Any tips will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

S.P.

**Second edit**. Here is `dj1_net/urls.py` (thanks, scytale):

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'dj1_net.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^dj1_net/', include('dj1_net.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: I included plain-text links since I'm not allowed to post images yet, but I guess it isn't a very good idea. I have added the error using code format. Thanks.

Comment: I just added it. By the way, without altering it "it worked" before activating admin, but now it doesn't. Having to now fix urls.py would be really puzzling... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a url defined for the root of your site. You'll need to add one, for example:

```
url(r'^$', 'dj1_net.views.my_view_function'),
```

That would go after the line that defines the admin URL.

Comment: Oops! I guess that's Part 3 of the tutorial, huh? I'm sorry for all the fuss. I just didn't expect enabling the admin site to "break" the standard ("it works") response... Thank you.